# For probability measures $P,Q$ with $Q\ll P$, does it hold that $Q[A]=1\Rightarrow P[A]=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, absolute-continuity

We work on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and suppose that $Q$ is a probability measure s.t. $Q\ll P$, i.e. for $A\in\mathcal{F}$ with $P[A]=0$, also $Q[A]=0$.

Suppose $A\in\mathcal{F}$ with $Q[A]=1$. Then $P[A]>0$. **Question**: Does it even hold that $P[A]=1$?

**Motivation**: If we have that $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent, then a statement that is $P$-a.s. true is also $Q$-a.s. true and vice versa. If $Q$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $P$, then a statement that is $P$-a.s. true is also $Q$-a.s. true. I would like to understand if the converse holds.

**My progress so far**: For any $B∈\mathcal{F}$ we have: $$P[B]=1⇒P[B^c]=0⇒Q[B^c]=0⇒Q[B]=1$$ Thus, $Q[B]<1⇒P[B]<1$.

Another result that might be helpful (a proof is for example in Prop. 2.1 [here](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Eeugeniam/math205a/L3.pdf)): $Q\ll P$ is equivalent to: $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0$ s.t. $P[B]<\delta \Rightarrow Q[B]<\epsilon$.

Any help on how to proceed with the proof, or, in case the statement is wrong, a (hint for a) counterexample is very much appreciated.

Comment: $P(A)=1-P(A^{c})$ and $Q(A)=1-Q(A^{c})$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Since $Q\ll P$ and $Q[A]=1$, it follows that $P[A]>0$. But can we say more?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @JoseAvilez For any $B\in\mathcal{F}$ we have: $P[B]=1\Rightarrow P[B^c]=0 \Rightarrow Q[B^c]=0 \Rightarrow Q[B]=1$. Thus, $Q[B]<1 \Rightarrow P[B]<1$. I am not sure if this helps.

Comment: @hannah Please edit your post to display your efforts. Also, please read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to ensure your questions don't get downvoted in the future.

Comment: @JoseAvilez Edited.

Comment: The Radon-Nikodym theorem gives a nice framework to think about this question.  Have you been introduced to Radon-Nikodym derivatives yet?  (We can still talk about the same type of counterexamples without explicit reference to these objects, but if you do know them, it just amounts to looking at the support of functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; for this counterexample, we work in $\Omega = [0,1]$ equipped with its Borel structure. Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure and $\delta_0$ the Dirac mass at zero. Set $P = \frac{1}{2}\lambda + \frac{1}{2} \delta_0$ and $Q = \lambda$.

To show absolute continuity, suppose $A \in \mathcal{F}$ has $P(A)=0$. Then this means that $0 \not\in A$ and $\lambda (A) = 0$, which implies that $Q(A) = 0$. Thus, $Q \ll P$. However, note that $Q((0,1]) = 1$, but $P((0,1]) = 0.5$, showing your claim is not true.